# Plot date and time on a matplotlib scatter graph using lists

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to create a python matplotlib scatter graph, where the x axis is the date and the y axis is time. I would like to be able to use two individual lists like below.

```
  dates = ['2015-12-20','2015-09-12']
  times = ['22:50:12','19:33:09']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `plot_date` instead of `scatter`. It may give you what you need.

```
import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.dates import date2num


def date_to_days(date):
    return date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))


def time_to_hours(time):
    [hh, mm, ss] = [int(x) for x in time.split(':')]
    seconds = datetime.timedelta(hours=hh, minutes=mm, seconds=ss).seconds
    hours = seconds / float(3600)
    return hours


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_date = '2015-08-01'
    end_date = '2015-12-31'

    dates = ['2015-12-20','2015-09-12']
    times = ['22:50:12','19:33:09']

    days = [date_to_days(d) for d in dates]
    hours = [time_to_hours(t) for t in times]

    plt.plot_date(days, hours, ydate=False)
    plt.axis([date_to_days(start_date), date_to_days(end_date), 0, 24])
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Time (hours)')
    plt.show()
```